# Jasmine/Protractor ReferenceError: inject is not defined with Angular + ngMocks

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, jasmine, protractor

I'm trying to run an e2e test with angular-mocks so that I can inject $cookies. I've added the angular.js and angular-mocks.js files into my specRunner.html.jst file - located in bower_components/jasmine/grunt/templates, which seems odd because I don't use grunt to run these tests - and I still get the error:

`ReferenceError: inject is not defined`

pointing to my beforeEach block.

Code:

```
describe('The portfolio manager route', function () {

var testedId = '1';
var expect_tabs_len_start = 0;
var expect_tabs_len_end = 2;
var company_count = 0;
...

var _queries = {
    "company_tick": ["PFE", 1 ],
    "company_name": ["Cephalon", 1],
    "drugname_full": ["Ambien", 2],
    "drugname_generic": ["zolpidem", 5]
};

beforeEach(inject(function ($cookies) {
    $cookies['user_portfolio_name'] = 0;
}));

...
```

specRunner.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Jasmine Spec Runner v<%= jasmineVersion %></title>

  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="lib/jasmine-<%= jasmineVersion %>/jasmine_favicon.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/jasmine-<%= jasmineVersion %>/jasmine.css">

  <script src="lib/jasmine-<%= jasmineVersion %>/jasmine.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/jasmine-<%= jasmineVersion %>/jasmine-html.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/jasmine-<%= jasmineVersion %>/boot.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js"></script>

  <!-- include source files here... -->
  <script src="src/Player.js"></script>
  <script src="src/Song.js"></script>

  <!-- include spec files here... -->
  <script src="spec/SpecHelper.js"></script>
  <script src="spec/PlayerSpec.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think this is a protractor question.

Comment: You may be right...I solved the issue with a simple `browser.manage().addCookie('user_portfolio_name', "1");` + a page refresh in my test block.